# Verification of Epsilon-Delta proof.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 3 }{ { -(x-3 })^{-2  }=-∞ } $$

$\ -(x-3 )^{-2  }< M<0$

$\ (x-3 )^{-2  }> |M|$

$\ (x-3 )^{2  }< 1/|M| $

$\ |x-3|<1/{\sqrt{|M|}} $

$\ 0<|x-3|<$

$\ <1/{\sqrt{|M|}}$

Since a delta can be obtained for all negative values of M, the limit is correct

Is the proof logically correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **idea** is correct, but not your way of expressing it. It should be:\begin{align}-(x-3 )^{-2  }< M&\iff(x-3 )^{-2  }> |M|\text{ (assuming $M<0$)}\\&\iff\ (x-3 )^{2  }< \frac1{|M|}\\&\iff\ |x-3|<\frac1{\sqrt{|M|}}.\end{align}Therefore, if we take $\delta=\frac1{\sqrt{|M|}}$, we have$$|x-3|<\delta\implies-(x-3 )^{-2  }< M$$

Comment: This was mainly just unorganized scratch work. I will work on structure. Thanks for the answer.